# Combining two dataframes of different dimensions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I want to combine two data frames of different dimensions. Take a look at the following:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id1=c(A,B,C), var1=(1,2,3), var2=(4,5,6))
df2 <- data.frame(id2=c(A,B,C,D,E), var3=c(5,6,7,8,9))
```

Output required:

```
id   var1   var2   var3
A    1       4      5
B    2       5      6
C    3       6      7
D    NA      NA     8
E    NA      NA     9
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can use `merge(df1, df2, by.x="id1", by.y="id2", all=TRUE)` for this example. Of if you perfer dplyr: `dplyr::full_join(df1, df2, by=c("id1"="id2"))`